# Change default resolution list in Visual Studio Simulator for Windows 8 Apps

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to change the default screen resolution list in the Visual Studio Simulator for Windows 8 apps?

Answer (score 14):

The simulator looks for additional resolution configurations using the following pattern

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Simulator\12.0\HardwareConfigurations\HardwareConfigurations*.xml
```

So if you copy the following XML into a file called `HardwareConfigurations-SurfacePro3.xml` in that folder (you need administrator rights) you get an extra entry in the list allowing you to simulate running on a Surface Pro 3.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArrayOfHardwareConfiguration xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <HardwareConfiguration>
        <Name>12-2160x1440</Name>
        <DisplayName>12" 2160 x 1440 (3:2, 140%)</DisplayName>
        <Resolution>
            <Height>1440</Height>
            <Width>2160</Width>
        </Resolution>
        <DeviceSize>12</DeviceSize>
        <DeviceScaleFactor>140</DeviceScaleFactor>
    </HardwareConfiguration>
</ArrayOfHardwareConfiguration>
```

[image: Surface Pro 3 resolution in simulator]

Comment: this works for me, strange thing is that even MS employees claims that this can be done - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27008949/351383

Comment: The simulator is a WPF app so I used Snoop to find the DataContext for the dropdown. Then I used JustDecompile to look around the code to find out where the contents came from. You can also add them to a config section in Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe.config if you like. FWIW you cannot extend the list in the device pane in Visual Studio 2013 as that list is hard-coded.

Answer (score 0):

According to what I found, it is not possible for now.

From this [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/09/29/first-look-at-windows-simulator.aspx), it says "*The availability of resolutions in the Palette depends upon the supported resolutions of your video card.*"