# WinRT App for Surface Pro 3 resolution issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime

I'm developing an app mainly for Surface Pro 2 and 3. Visual Studio 2013 supports Surface Pro 2 well with the simulator (10.6" 1920 X 1080 (16:9, 140%)) but there is now way to simulate the Surface Pro 3 resolution.

[The guidelines for scaling to pixel density](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465362.aspx) talk about three scalings: 1.0, 1.4 and 1.8 which are automatically supported.

1.4 is for Surface Pro 2 or a full hd resolution but my Surface Pro 3 shows me also a 140% scaling. I'm wondering why, I've expected a higher scaling. With 140% scaling I have a lot of unused space on the bottom.

Is there a way to set the scaling manually to e.g. 150%? What's best for support the Surface Pro 3 resolution? Is it possible that the Visual Studio simulator supports 2160 X 1440?

Comment: And then there's also snapview. I think supporting various resolutions and ratios _dynamically_ is (y)our only option on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the simulator can be made to support 2160 x 1440 (and other resolutions)
See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27501159/1260066

Answer (score 0):

I'd check [the guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465362.aspx). Windows only supports 100/140/180% scales (and IIRC 80% in the start screen) and I don't believe you can force it to switch from the scale you get in your app. You also don't get the Surface Pro 3 display profile in the simulator or Blend and I'm not aware of any way to hack it.

You should use the layout panels to arrange things in your UI to make them look good. If you don't have a Surface Pro 3 to test it on - you could temporarily set your UI root dimensions to 2160x1440 and put it in a Viewbox. For testing different layout configurations at runtime - you can use XAML Spy or WinRT XAML Toolkit Debugging tools to tweak the UI of your app while it runs. I'm not actually sure if you can modify properties in XAML Spy since I haven't used it in a while, but I know you can with the Toolkit because I wrote it.