# Custom Size in Windows 8.1 Simulator

Tags: windows-8.1, simulator, screen-resolution, screen-size, modern-ui

I have been searching this over the web for 2 days now and I am still unable to get my hands on something helpful. I have to run my windows 8.1 app on large device (i-e 80 inches) having 4k(3840 X 2160) resolution. The max resolution I have on the windows simulator is 2560 x 1440 (i-e 27 inches). Is there any way that I can add custom screen size/resolution to windows simulator? or is there any other option available where I can test my app on 4k resolution?

PS: I don't have a 4k device with me right now, that's why I want to test it on some simulator.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change default resolution list in Visual Studio Simulator for Windows 8 Apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13185091/change-default-resolution-list-in-visual-studio-simulator-for-windows-8-apps)

Answer (score 0):

The simulator doesn't support custom resolutions.

If you design your UI to be flexible and test it at a variety of resolutions and DPI levels you should be able to get a pretty good idea of how it will work. Running at 1920x1080 will give the same ratio as 3840x2160, just scaled by half in each direction.

You can request feature updates for the Windows Dev Platform at http://wpdev.uservoice.com